# fpdf multicell not holding text in the cell width

Tags: php, fpdf

My Code:

```
$pdf=new FPDI();
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($spath);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFontSize(15);
$pdf->SetXY (25,80);
$pdf->MultiCell(50,15,'&asdasdasdasd sa dasdas d as dsas sasadsa sa akhggfhghfgh fhfhfghfh fhfhfg f gh fjkhkjkllkk&',1,'L',false);
```

Problem is that, the text is not wrapped inside the cell.

Example:

[image]
1

If I do center text, this happens:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',15); This line fixed it. Looks like u need to set font type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

$pdf->Cell(0,15, '&asdasdasdasd sa dasdas d as dsas sasadsa sa akhggfhghfgh fhfhfghfh fhfhfg f gh fjkhkjkllkk&  :',1, 2);

Comment: no i need muticell for the line break option, anyway found the problem. I added font type and its working now.